# /etc/cron.hourly in home directory

Tags: cron

How does one run scripts in a folder on a schedule without needing to bother with root/sudo? Ubuntu has `/etc/cron.hourly`, `/etc/cron.daily`, etc so I was wondering if there was also a folder in the home directory it looks at.

Answer (score 2):

First we need to generate the folders we can put scripts in:

```
mkdir ~/.config/cron.hourly
mkdir ~/.config/cron.daily
mkdir ~/.config/cron.weekly
mkdir ~/.config/cron.monthly
mkdir ~/.config/cron.yearly
mkdir ~/.config/cron.reboot
```

Then we need to run `crontab -e` to edit our scheduler. If this is you're first time running crontab, you'll need to select your terminal editor first (use nano, the default). Then paste:

```
@hourly ( cd ~ && run-parts --report /home/$(whoami)/.config/cron.hourly )
@daily ( cd ~ && run-parts --report /home/$(whoami)/.config/cron.daily )
@weekly ( cd ~ && run-parts --report /home/$(whoami)/.config/cron.weekly )
@monthly ( cd ~ && run-parts --report /home/$(whoami)/.config/cron.monthly )
@yearly ( cd ~ && run-parts --report /home/$(whoami)/.config/cron.yearly )
@reboot ( cd ~ && run-parts --report /home/$(whoami)/.config/cron.reboot )
```

(nano) hit `Ctrl+X` to close, type `y` to save, confirm filename with `enter`.

Now you can put any script you want in those folders to run on a schedule.

Note: In your scripts, commands outside of the default `PATH` `/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` will need their full path.

Note: `@reboot` is special and only runs when you cold boot (not when you restart) the pc.

You also might want to install `sudo apt-get install postfix` (select local only) to log any stdout/stderr your scripts make in the file `/var/mail/$USER`.

Comment: You might want to include a warning that the default PATH in which commands are searched is very restricted (`/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` IIRC) and that that influences what the scripts under `~/.config/cron.*` can invoke without specifying a fulll path).

Comment: Is that so? Hmmm. I wonder how you'd get the same `$PATH` as in bash. Would you need be able to set it in crontab? does the `run-parts` call strip the path, needing you to use `source ~/.bashrc` or whatever it is in your script?

Comment: besides I have read somewhere that only file starting with a digit are run. (e.g. `998-foo.sh` , not `foo.sh`), which by the way is very handy to know in which order file are executed.

Comment: @Zren You can set the PATH while editing your crontab, that would affect both the crontab entries, and any scripts they run (`PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/bin`  e.g.)

Comment: @Archemar `run-parts` excludes executables with special characters, but I'm not aware of any requirement that they start with a number; see [the manpage](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=run-parts&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en) for details.